# Select and highlight on a kendo chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Is there anyway to select, drag and highlight a specific area on an area/line chart?  I have a chart plotted with a series.  I want to allow the user to left-click and drag an area on that chart and just return the select categoryAxis values (i.e. from/to).  Is this possible?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/selection

Comment: No, I want to mouse click and drag to select a range of data.